Does series acceleration improve computational efficiency?
There are several methods of series acceleration.
For example, Euler's transform is:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^na_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} a_{n-k}$$
The left-hand side is one addition or subtraction for each step.The right-hand side has many operations and the computational complexity is obviously higher.
Does series acceleration improve the ratio of computational effort to error? If not, what are the advantages?

According to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersSeriesTransformation.html#:~:text=Euler%27s%20series%20transformation%20is%20a%20transformation%20that%20sometimes,%28k%3D0%29%5Einfty%20%28-1%29%5Eka_k%2C%20%281%29%20Abramowitz%20and%20Stegun%20%281972%2C%20p., it sometimes can accelerate. Not a guaranteed claim.
